# Use Proof By Induction to find the product of consecutive odd integers up to $2n-1$

Tags: products

I'm a bit stuck on this inductive proof. I have to find what this is equal to. Product of $1 \times 3 \times 5 \times \ldots \times (2n-1)$ Starting with $i= 1$. What would be a good starting point?

Comment: Do you know what $\prod_{k=1}^n k$ is? You are looking for $\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)$. Hint: divide one by the other and simplify.

Comment: ∏nk=1k is the factorial?

Comment: The answer is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$, now go prove this by induction.

Comment: yes, exactly. Now divide it by what you have to get the missing terms, and reduce it to a different factorial

Comment: Induction doesn't really solve such problems, it just helps you prove a solution works once you've got a conjectured expression.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Whatever $$\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)$$ is, if we multiply it by $$\prod_{k=1}^n(2k),$$ then we'll end up with $(2n)!$ as a product. Try simplifying the second expression, so that you can get an explicit expression for the first.