# Show that $\frac{(2n)!}{(n)!}=2^n(2n-1)!!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, binomial-theorem

Show that $\frac{(2n)!}{(n)!}=2^n(2n-1)!!$ is the question I am struggling with.

I started by saying: $(2n)!=2n(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)...3*2*1$

But then I'm stuck.

Comment: I'm almost positively certain that this was asked before.

Comment: Reeks of induction.

Comment: @GitGud: No, there's a clear and beautiful solution.

Comment: It's not correct, did you mean $(2n-1)!!$ the double factorial?

Comment: @Asaf Does expanding (2n)! and watching the cancellations occur, count as "beautiful"?

Comment: @Did: Yes, comparatively to a long induction anyway.

Comment: You can factor $ 2^n$ from the terms $ 2n(2n-2)(2n-4)...4.2$.

Comment: [Closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/351308/28900).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$(2n)!=\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k)\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)=2^n\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)=2^n\cdot n!\cdot(2n-1)!!$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{2n!}{n!} = \frac{1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}{1\cdot2\cdot\ldots \cdot n}=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)\cdot2\cdot4\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}{1\cdot2\cdot\ldots \cdot n} = \frac{1\cdot3\cdot\ldots(2n-1)\cdot2^n\cdot 1\cdot2\cdot\ldots \cdot n}{1\cdot2\cdot\ldots \cdot n} = 2^n\cdot1\cdot3\cdot\ldots \cdot (2n-1)=2^n(2n-1)!!$$

Comment: @Pauly...if you call 'helping' = 'doing the entire problem for you'